# need for header node

Tags: data-structures

we say that a header linked list is that which consists of a special node called header node that marks the beginning of the list 
but i dont understand what is really the importance of this header node.
please help me?

Comment: Your question is too vague to be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having sentinel nodes prevents you from having to handle certain edge cases.

The biggest is the null check: You always know that there will be a node at the top of the list that you can insert nodes after, so you don't have to deal with checking if head is null. (also it helps having a tail node for similar reasons)

Consider the two cases:

With a head and a tail node:

```
addNewDataAtHead( data ):
    newNode = new Node(data);
    newNode.next = head.next;
    newNode.prev = head;
    head.next.prev = newNode;
    head.next = newNode;
```

Without:

```
addNewDataAtHead( data ):
    newNode = new Node(data);
    if (head == null):
        head = newNode;
    newNode.next = head;
    head.prev = newNode;
    head =  newNode;
```

the intent of the first one is a lot clearer because it is like inserting anywhere else. The second case requires you to check for a special circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

There's a certain sort of linked list where you can greatly simplify the appending, insertion and deletion code, at the cost of a little storage and minimal extra effort in traversing the list.

That's because an empty list looks like this:

```
        +-------+    +-------+
head -> | dummy | -> | dummy | -> null
null <- | head  | <- | tail  | <- tail
        +-------+    +-------+
```

Instead of worrying about whether you're appending to (or inserting into) an empty list, or whether your deletion will create an empty list, it's a lot simpler.

The initialisation becomes slightly more complex, original on the left, modified on the right as per *all* the code below. This usually doesn't cause a problem since list creation happens *once* but insertions and deletions happen a lot.

```
def init ():                            def init ():
    head = null                             head = new node
    tail = null                             tail = new node
                                            head->next = tail
                                            head->prev = null
                                            tail->prev = head
                                            tail->next = null
```

Compare the classic append (insert is even more complex since you may need to insert before `head`, in the middle, or after `tail`) with the simplified one:

```
def append (node):                      def append (node):
    node->next = null                       node->next = tail
    if head == null:                        node->prev = tail->prev
        head = node                         tail->prev = node
        tail = node
        node->prev = null
    else:
        tail->next = node
        node->prev = tail
        tail = node
```

The deletion is also greatly simplified since, with a classic linked list, there's a lot of checking to ensure you don't dereference a null pointer:

```
def delete (node):                      def delete (node):
    if node == head and node == tail:       if node != head and node != tail:
        head = null                             node->prev->next = node->next
        tail = null                             node->next->prev = node->prev
    elsif node == head:                         free node
        head = head->next
        head->prev = null
    elsif node == tail:
        tail = tail->prev
        tail->next = null
    else:
        node->prev->next = node->next
        node->next->prev = node->prev
    free node
```

The code for traversing the list needs to exclude the dummy nodes of course but that's a trivial change:

```
def traverse (head):                    def traverse (head):
    node = head                             node = head->next
    while node != null:                     while node != tail:
        do something with node                  do something with node
        node = node->next                       node = node->next
```

---

Myself, I'm not a big fan of code like this since it may indicate people are too lazy to understand how the data structures and algorithms work. I'd much rather have the more complex code since it shows an indication that the person can think things through. In any case, this is the sort of thing you only tend to write once.